# Harmonic function imply divergence and curl are $0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

A little confused about 4(ii).  First I assume you apply Green's theorem to $\int_{C} U_y dx-U_x dy$, but with the assumption that $U$ is harmonic this seems to lead to $0$.  Moreover I thought green's theorem only applies to closed curves.

Also can someone do (iii) (a) or (b) for sake of example.

Answer (score 1):

For question 4(ii), you need to show that the integral from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ is independent of the path along which we integrate.

To do so, consider a simple, closed curve $\gamma$ passing through both points. Since $U$ is harmonic, we can apply Green's Theorem to obtain that the line integral is zero. Then, we have $\int_{\gamma} U_y dx - U_x dy = \int_{\gamma_1} U_y dx - U_x dy + \int_{\gamma_2} U_y dx - U_x dy = 0$, where $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are the portions of $\gamma$ that lie on opposite sides of the line joining $(0,0)$ and $(x,y)$, with the same orientation as $\gamma$.

All that is left to do is to reverse the orientation of $\gamma_2$ to obtain $\int_{\gamma_1} U_y dx - U_x dy = \int_{\gamma_2^{'}} U_y dx - U_x dy$, with $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2^{'}$ now oriented from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$. This shows path independence.

For 3, applying the procedure outlined here will give you $G(x,y)$.

Comment: Basically, $C$ along which the question wants you to integrate isn't supposed to be closed. You complete a closed path by going back from your point to $(0,0)$ and then apply Green's Theorem.

Comment: How about the div G and Curl G equal 0?